# Swift Bond bidirectionalBind Generic parameter 'B' could not be inferred

Tags: ios, swift, swiftbond

I'm getting an error: `Generic parameter 'B' could not be inferred` when trying to do a [Bond](https://github.com/DeclarativeHub/Bond) `bidirectionalBind` with a non optional string and a `UITextField`. With a optional string it works fine.

Below is some example Swift Code that demonstrates this error.

```
protocol ItemModel {
    var _id: Observable<String> { get set }
    var title: Observable<String?> { get set }
}

class Item: NSObject, ItemModel {
    var _id: Observable<String> = Observable<String>("")
    var title: Observable<String?> = Observable<String?>(nil)
}

class MyViewModel {
    var pendingItem: Item? = Item()
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    private var viewModel: MyViewModel = MyViewModel()

    @IBOutlet var id: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var titleField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel.pendingItem?._id.bidirectionalBind(to: id.reactive.text) // fails with error: Generic parameter 'B' could not be inferred
        viewModel.pendingItem?.title.bidirectionalBind(to: titleField.reactive.text)
    }
}
```

The problem is when trying to setup the `bidirectionalBind` to the `_id` it fails with the following error:

> Generic parameter 'B' could not be inferred

Everything is exactly the same between the `_id` and `title` except for the fact that the `title` is optional while the `_id` is not. That is the only thing I can figure out why it's failing.

Therefor I think the question is, how can I do a `bidirectionalBind` in Bond to a UITextField on a non optional string variable? But more generally, how can I fix this error?

---

Some other information. Just from a usability standpoint, if `id.text` is `nil` which means the UITextField is empty, I'd like it to just default to an empty string. I know that I can't set it to `nil` because `_id` is not optional. So setting the default value in case it is `nil` to an empty string is completely fine by me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Bond, however a bidirectional bind would mean that the text field will also update the property, and you cannot send an optional to a non-optional property. Maybe try an unidirectional bind?

Comment: @Cristik There are certain reasons I want a bidirectional bind in this case. For example later on there will be this part where I edit the value in code and need that to be reflected to the user.

Comment: Then you can either change the `_id` to hold a `String?`, or add a new observable to `UITextField` that maps over a non-optional string, whichever feels more comfortable.